# Resumir textos dinâmicos em PHP com jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Eu consegui fazer a função de *Ver Mais*, com um código aqui do StackOverflow, porém os textos vem do banco dinâmicos, ou seja como eu faço pra esse código pegar cada texto?

Código em php:

```
< div class="box-body" id="texto">
    <?php
        $texto = htmlentities($row['texto']);
        $texto = preg_replace('/[\n\r]{1,}/',"\n\n",$texto);
        echo nl2br(emoticons($texto)); 
    ?>
</ div>
```

Código em Jquery:

```
var wordLimit = 50;
$(function() {
  //trata o conteúdo na inicialização da página
  $('#texto').each(function() {
    var post = $(this);
    var text = post.text();
    //encontra palavra limite
    var re = /[\s]+/gm, results = null, count = 0;
    while ((results = re.exec(text)) !== null && ++count < wordLimit) { }
    //resume o texto e coloca o link
    if (results !== null && count >= wordLimit) {
      var summary = text.substring(0, re.lastIndex - results[0].length);
      post.text(summary + '...');
      post.data('original-text', text);
      post.append('<br/><a href="#" class="read-more">Leia mais</a>');
    }
  });

  //ao clicar num link "Leia mais", mostra o conteúdo original
  $('.read-more').on('click', function() {
    var post = $(this).closest('#texto');
    var text = post.data('original-text');
    post.text(text);
  });

});
```

Comment: Florida, pode me ajudar?

Comment: Desculpe, não posso, mas se você aguardar um pouco algun usuário com mais experiencia do que eu talvez lhe ajude, como é final de semana, talvez não estejam por aqui. _Lembre-se, quanto mais detalhes você der sobre o que esta fazendo e como quer que fique, mas fácil será para algum interessado compreender e te ajudar_.

Comment: @Florida, olha ta dificil, é o terceiro post que faço aqui e só no vacuo :\

Comment: Tenha calma, é preciso esperar, não podemos forçar ninguém a responder nada. Enquanto alguém não responde, você vai tentando resolver, e caso consiga, você mesmo pode responder a sua própria pergunta.

Comment: Uma dúvida, o que quer dizer com textos dinâmicos? Quer dizer que esse texto pode ter tamanho variado ou que podem haver entradas na tabela onde voce salva esse texto e que deveriam ser puxadas simultâneamente?

Comment: Que serão vários textos vindo do banco de dados. Eu até consegui fazer colocando um id diferente pra cada DIV, porém aí teria que colocar cada script pra cada div, ia ficar horrível, queria só uma pra todas.

Comment: Você não pode ter o mesmo id em mais de um elemento. Use uma classe e troque `#texto` por `.sua-classe` no jquery.

Comment: Mas aí vão ter varias divs com a mesma classe por exemplo

Comment: < div class="oi">texto 1</ div> < div class="oi">texto 2</ div>

Comment: E assim não funciona :\

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado, era isso mesmo, não sei pq

Comment: @ViniciusHenzel agora você pode responder a sua própria pergunta se quiser, ira ajudar outros no futuro. :)

Comment: obrigado @Florida

Comment: Só um adendo sobre ter vários elementos com a mesma classe, bom, essa é a função da classe, agrupar elementos similares que são da mesma, vejam só, classe...haha

Answer (score 1):

Sempre que tenho de fazer isso, faço dessa forma, que acho mais simples:

```js
$(function(){
  // escondo todos os textos completos
  $('.more').hide();
  
  // quando clicar em ver mais
  $('.see').click(function(){
    // pego o ID
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    // mostro a publicação completa do post
    $('section#p'+id+' > .more').show('fast');
    // oculto o resumo daquele post
    $('section#p'+id+' > .abstract').hide('fast');
  });
  
  // quando clicar em ver menos
  $('.hide').click(function(){
    // pego o ID
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    // oculto a publicação completa do post
    $('section#p'+id+' > .more').hide('fast');
    // mostro o resumo daquele post
    $('section#p'+id+' > .abstract').show('fast');
  });
});
```

```css
.post { 
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section class="post" id="p1">
  <div class="abstract">
    Texto resumido pelo php est...
    <a href="#" class="see" id="1" >Ver Mais</a>
  </div>

  <div class="more">
    <p>Texto resumido pelo php está completo agora</p>
    <a href="#" class="hide" id="1" >Ver Menos</a>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="post" id="p4">
  <div class="abstract">
    Mais um post com descrição ...
    <a href="#" class="see" id="4" >Ver Mais</a>
  </div>

  <div class="more">
    <p>Mais um post com descrição resumida com PHP que agora 
    está sendo exibido inteiro</p>
    <a href="#" class="hide" id="4" >Ver Menos</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: muito bom, é muito melhor assim em PHP, pois não demora pra carregar